# Can workflow update the list columns of an item that has item level permission(Read Nothing/ None)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, item-level-permissions

I have SharePoint list called 'Onboarding Particulars' that contains items belonging to different departments. Mr. 'A' in the company head office(full control permission on the site) creates an item in this list for a particular deprtment and in one of the fields(Person or Group) he enters the email address of the concerned department head(Mr. 'B'). As soon as Mr. 'A' saves this item a workflow assigns a task to Mr. 'B' asking him to get the remaining fields of this list filled. If the head office does not want Mr. 'B' to view and edit the items of other deprtments that are present in the 'Onboarding Particulars' list-

1. What permissions should be given to Mr. 'B' on the 'Onboarding Particulars' list?
2. What permissions should be given to Mr. 'B' on the workflow list so that he does not see tasks of other people because he might get into the 'Onboarding list' from here?

Comment: Is Flow an option for the workflow?

Comment: I had Flow as the way forward and an option in my mind. But I also think that in the end it is SharePoint that gets updated and persmissions may still play their part. Besides this I also do not know whether Flow has the same behavior as that of SharePoint designer workflows. In SharePoint the permissions of the person who starts the workflow gets applied. So ideally if a person with full control starts the workflow all remaining folks in the chain should be able to complete the process.